# Android - Launching an IntentService from Settings via XML or Java and passing data to said service

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, onclicklistener, intentservice

I have an app that has a notification and from the settings I want the user to be able to test the notification to see if they set it up properly. The notification activity has a Boolean variable `runOnce` that I'd like to set to true via the intent data passed to the activity.
I have this so far -

```
<Preference
        android:summary="Test the notification to ensure the settings are correct"
        android:title="Test Notification" 
        android:key="testNotification">
            <intent android:action="com.orbitdesign.testApp.refreshNotificationIntentService" /> 
    </Preference>
```

but this creates an error that the intent doesn't exist.

So I guess my question is twofold,

First, how do I launch an `IntentService` class from a settings menu via `XML`?

Second, is there a better way to accomplish this, pehaps via an `onClickListener` in the `Settings.java` class? How would I implement such a thing?

Also I need to pass `runOnce = true` to the `refreshNotificationIntentService` or else it won't run. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me -

```
testNotification.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Log.d(TAG, "testNotification clicked");

            Intent intent = new Intent(UserSettingActivity.this, RefreshNotificationIntentService .class);
            startService(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```